# String literals in Define preprocessor directive

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor

I would like to the `#define` directive inside of a quotation.  Here's the problem:

There is a built-in function in the embedded platform that I'm using that takes literal assembly code as a string.  I would like to wrap this into a macro.

```
__asm__("goto 0x2400");
```

The above built-in function the processor jumps to the code at location 0x2400 and starts executing at that address (for those wondering, I'm writing a bootloader which is why this is necessary).  Because the address is in the string, I cannot easily replace it.  I need a way to make the function generic so that I can start executing code at any address.  For example:

```
#define ASM_GOTO __asm__("goto X")
```

This will not result in a correct text replacement because the X is in quotes.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#define ASM_GOTO(X) __asm__("goto " #X)
```

This has a slight problem, though:

```
#define MAGIC_ADDRESS 0x2400
ASM_GOTO(MAGIC_ADDRESS);
```

Results in `__asm__("goto " "MAGIC_ADDRESS");`, which I expect isn't what you want.

So,

```
#define STRINGIZE(X) #X
#define ASM_GOTO(X) __asm__("goto " STRINGIZE(X))
```

is probably more like it, since in the expansion of `ASM_GOTO`, `X` gets expanded before `STRINGIZE` acts on it.

If you didn't already know, be aware that although the result from the preprocessor is `"goto " "0x2400"` (two string literal tokens), they're combined during compilation into a single string literal (5.1.1.2/6 of C99). This occurs after macros are expanded (4), but before semantic analysis (7).

Comment: This works.  Thanks for the idea to use two defines.  I was stuck at the first one.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#define ASM_GOTO(X) __asm__("goto "#X)
```

Comment: This does not work if you define the address in another define.  See chosen answer for the error.

Comment: Indeed. But it does work for the question as originally posted. If you wanted expansion of symbolic addresses then you should really have stated this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [stringize operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Quoting_macro_arguments).  Something like:

```
#define ASM_GOTO(x) __asm("goto " #x)
```

should do what you need it to do.

Comment: This does not work if you define the address in another define.  See chosen answer for the error.